# how to set NGINX

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I try to set to my ubuntu 16.04 nginx by terminal. I already have apach. When I follow this instructions
 sudo apt update

`sudo apt install nginx`

all good, but when I put ufw status    I see just this:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to configure UFW for nginx you can do

```
ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
```